# Splitting large csv file by column first letter according to alphabetic order linux

Tags: python, linux, csv, unix, awk

I want to split a large csv file containing rows as follows:

```
1,amine,22,001
2,amy,35,224
3,david,80,77
```

using the 2nd column's first letter and according to alphabetic order so the result should be 2 files:

```
a.csv:
1,amine,22,001
2,amy,35,224
```

and

```
d.csv:
3,david,80,77
```

Thanks!

Comment: please show your attempts

Comment: I think the description should be corrected to use 2nd column's 1st letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's (perhaps surprisingly) straightforward

```sh
awk -F, '{print > (substr($2,1,1) ".csv")}' large.csv
```

Comment: While that would work with gawk, it would fail with other awks once you've created about 15 output files due to "too many open files". Gotta close 'em as you go if you want portability.

Comment: Only 15? I figured I would be OK with (hopefully) just 26

Comment: It usually fails at less than 20 in my experience. For example, there's a question at https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/276530-awk-date-too-many-open-files.html where it failed after reading the 33rd input line and it looks like there'd be multiple lines in each output file so I expect that was in the under-20 range of output files. YMMV on the limit, looks like others get into the thousands before hitting it.

Answer (score 3):

The robust, portable, efficient way to do this is (untested):

```
sort -t',' -k2,2 file |
awk -F',' '
{ key = substr($2,1,1) }
key != prev {
    close(out)
    out = key ".csv"
    prev = key
}
{ print > out }
'
```

The above assumes you don't care about the order of the lines in each output file.

Answer (score 0):

`python` solution, let `file.csv` content be

```
1,amine,22,001
2,amy,35,224
3,david,80,77
```

and `splitter.py` located in same catalog be

```
def get_output_filename(row):
    return row[row.index(",")+1]+".csv"
with open("file.csv","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        with open(get_output_filename(line),"a") as g:
             g.write(line)
```

then

```
python splitter.py
```

will create files `a.csv` with content

```
1,amine,22,001
2,amy,35,224
```

and `d.csv` with content

```
3,david,80,77
```

Explanation: I wrote function `get_output_filename` which finds character directly after first `,` and concat it with `.csv`. `for line in f` avoids loading whole file to memory (thus `file.csv` might be bigger than memory), `a` mode is used for appending, output file is closed immediately after writing to it, so at any time at most 2 files are opened (one to reading and one to appending). Disclaimer: `python splitter.py` should be done exactly once.

*(tested in Python 3.8.10 and Python 2.7.18)*

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask for this, but just for fun since you already got answers in the languages you asked for, here's how you could do this in R:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread('input.csv')[, g := substr(V2, 1, 1)]
df[, fwrite(.SD, paste0(g, '.csv'), col.names = F), by = g]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shell solution:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r letter line 
do
    echo "$line" >> "$letter.csv"
done < <(sed -E 's/^([^,]*,)([a-z])(.*$)/\2\t\1\2\3/' file)
```

You need to add `rm *.csv` if there is a chance that there are previous files of the type `[a-z].csv` since `>>` appends each line to that file (and creates the file if it does not exist.)

The advantage here is the original order of lines in `file` is respected.